# How do I find out the recent negative information on my credit score?

Tags: united-states, credit-score, experian

I am accessing my Experian credit report from their website.  In the summary of my account there is a tab for "Negative Information", where it states that it has been 0.5 Years since the last time negative information was listed on one of my accounts.  However, my detailed report shows no negative information and all accounts in good standing.  The month-by-month listing of account standing shows "OK" for all months of all accounts.  I know that there was a late payment several years ago, but this is not indicated anywhere on the detailed report and was much longer than 0.5 years ago.  What could the negative information be?  Is there any way to get more details about it?

Comment: Could it mean that 0.5 years ago a reference to an older negative event (the late payment?) was removed from your record and no loner reported?

Comment: @User58220 That's a good thought, especially the way it's worded.  However, it's definitely presented as a *bad* thing, i.e., a reason for my score being lower.

Comment: @User58220, I guess you were close.  The late payment account is still on there, but it was closed 0.5 years from when I first asked this.  It seems like just a buggy website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more research, I think I've determined the solution.  My actual, 30-page credit report from Experian has a section for "**Potentially Negative Items or Items for Further Review**".  There is one account in this section—the one that had a late payment several years ago.  This account was also closed 0.5 years before I originally asked this question.

So the actual credit report is accurate.  The problem is how the Experian website interprets and summarizes the report: when an account with negative information closes (or maybe even just changes), they present it as if that's the date that the negative information occurred.

Answer (score 1):

First, contact the agency via phone as soon as possible.  Question them about why it shows that.  Make sure they have the correct information.  Some may argue to try and be sly about your late payment, but there is no way around it impacting you at one point or another and it probably is already there.  Find out what the more recent negative activity is so you can dispute it or find out what is wrong.  They can and are required to go through this with you.

My two guesses are as follows:

1. It is the late payment only updated on your report 0.5 years ago
   with Experian.
2. Something negative impacted you 0.5 years ago (Possibly something
   incorrect, hence the need to call Experian).

After calling Experian and resolving your issue, I would **HIGHLY** recommend contacting Transunion and Equifax by phone to make sure all three of them are on the same page.

Hope this helps, yes calling them sucks, but it is better to call than to risk your credit's health.